# An injection of Weyl groups

Tags: lie-algebras, coxeter-groups

I've shown, quite accidentally, that Weyl group of $F_4$ injects into the Weyl group of $E_6$ as the subgroup of elements normalizing a maximal torus $T^4$ of $F_4$. One might a priori expect other Weyl elements of $E_6$ to normalize this torus, but it isn't the case.

I came to this result through number crunching and realizing that the Weyl group of $E_6$ acts simply transitively on ordered quadruples of mutually orthogonal roots. The same statement doesn't hold for the inclusion $D_4 \to E_6$, for instance, so it doesn't seem like it should have been a priori obvious before I did this calculation.

1. **Is it actually a priori obvious?**

In any event, it must surely be known.

2. **Where can I find a citation?**

**Update**: I've received some responses on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203295/is-this-characterization-of-1-eigenspaces-of-the-weyl-group-of-e-6-known.

Comment: I know nothing about $F_4$ or $E_6$, so I find this incredibly non-obvious.  I know Cartan did a ton of work with the exceptional groups, so I'd start there.  I have no idea if he solved this problem or not.  (Incidentally, if you know of any place where a basis for $\mathfrak{f}_4$ as a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{so}(26)$ or $\mathfrak{so}(27)$ is actually written down, I'd be very interested in knowing it.  Such a description of $\mathfrak{g}_2$ as a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{so}(7)$ is given in Kerin's paper "Some new examples with almost positive curvature.")

Comment: My problem is that I still don't know anything about these groups beyond root systems either. It can be seen $W(E_6)$ acts simply transitively on ordered quadruples of mutually orthogonal roots. There are 135 *un*ordered such quadruples, spanning 45 different 4-planes $V$. Taking roots to coroots, one sees each of these is a Spin(8) whose maximal torus lies in the Cartan of $E_6$. Those are maximal tori of $F_4$s, as well, and it follows from orbit-stabilizer computations that the order of the stabilizer of one of them is $|W(F_4)| = 1152$, so nothing else in $W(E_6)$ stabilizes $V$.

Comment: Interesting question. Have you looked at R.W. Carter: Conjugacy classes in the Weyl group (Compositio Mathematica 25 (1972), p. 1-59],  http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/CM/CM_1972__25_1/CM_1972__25_1_1_0/CM_1972__25_1_1_0.pdf ?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: I have! One of his lemmas actually gave me the idea I should prove that $W_{E_6}$ acts (simply) transitively on ordered quadruples of mutually orthogonal roots (Carter stops at triples, but it's easy from there), which leads to the Weyl group statement by repeated application of orbit–stabilizer. But I didn't get much more than that out of Carter. I've also gotten some response on MO; I'll edit the question to include a link. They refer inter alia to Carter's book and suggest that this was known but may not have been stated anywhere else in just the terms I'd hoped for.

Comment: Aha, that makes it even more interesting. I have been thinking about this "folding" a lot recently. It seems like there is no comprehensive treatment of "quotient root systems" ($F_4$ is a quotient of $E_6$, $B_n$ of $D_{n+1}$, $C_n$ of $A_{2n-1}$) complementary to that of sub-root systems, even though they seem to come up at various places in the theory (I encountered them in the Tits-Borel(-Satake) classification of forms of simple Lie algebras / alg. groups over general fields).

Comment: The only sources I really know about this folding construction are the books on symmetric spaces by Loos and the papers by Joseph A. Wolf on homogeneous spaces defined by Lie group automorphisms (generalized symmetric spaces). But I believe they are fully classified. I originally saw this stuff in the discussion which is on p. 9 of the preprint of Goertsches and Noshari about equivariant formality of the isotropy actions $K \curvearrowright G/K$ associated to an automorphism $\sigma$ with $(G^{\langle\sigma\rangle})_0 = K$. These sources may all be familiar, but if not, I hope they help.